# Meaning of verb "cock" in "He cocked his head to the side."

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This sentence comes from a [novel](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ojkGAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y):

> "Huh. Wow. That is good news. So--" He **cocked** his head to the side. "--why don't you seem happy?"

OALD defines *cock* as:

> to raise a part of your body so that it is vertical or at an angle

However, I still don't understand/picture what the movement of the word *cock* is in this context, or when someone *cocks* his head, how does the head move?

Comment: It's titled sideways, so the length of the nose makes an angle to the ground. [Here's what you see](http://m.imgur.com/U5FM1MV) if you do a [Google Image Search for `cocked head`](https://www.google.com/search?q=cocked+head&client=safari&hl=en-us&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI2oHbgrmVyAIVDlKSCh3dKA2w).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means to turn the top of your head down to either the left or the right. One of the ears moves closer to the shoulder.